# Are there any parallels in other religions to the philosophy of Anekantavada found in Jainism?

Tags: eastern-philosophy, paradigm

At its basic Anekantavada is the doctrine of accommodation of multiple viewpoints into its fold. Basically, a pluralistic or diversity accommodative philosophy it is.

Does any other philosophical school or religions have similar doctrines?

Comment: Another *Modus Indorum* - perhaps history lessons, short & sweet, to the point, ones, are just what we need at this (critical?) juncture. Google fer more!

Comment: I looked it up. Wikipedia definition says: "*Anekāntavāda is the Jain doctrine about metaphysical truths that emerged in ancient India. It states that the ultimate truth and reality is complex and has multiple aspects. According to Jainism, no single, specific statement can describe the nature of existence and the absolute truth.*" It doesn't sound like what I understand Pluralism to be. More like Nonduality?

Comment: It is basic pluralism some form of relativism, nothing unique about it. All Indian vedic etc philosophies are derived from the Greeks. Just study the ancient Greek philosophies.

Comment: @Michael16 - Jainism is not Vedic. It is Indian origin. But is considered anti-Vedic or a heterodox (nastika) philosophy as per Hindu religion.

Comment: yes, I heard about it, but which gods or gurus do they worship? What are their temples for? this too has came from Greeks only, bec Greeks ruled over Gujrat Punjab 2thousand yrs ago or less.